# MySQL how to reduce transaction timeout on connection loss

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions

I'm trying to find a way to reduce the transaction timeout in the following usecase using Hibernate:

Start a transaction by calling `Transaction transaction = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction()`.
I update the ORM objects and pass them by calling `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);`.
At the end, I execute `transaction.commit();`

Sometimes it happens that while commit() is executed, the connection gets lost and an exception is thrown. I close the connection, so I'll get a new one from connection pool for the next transaction. My first question is, is it possible to rollback that transaction after reconnecting? As far as I've seen, this is not possible.

At the moment, if the user tries to execute this command again, a new transaction is created and committed. But now the server is in a locking state for around 15 minutes and it's not possible to execute any transactions on the server.

The innodb monitor output created by calling `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` looks like this:

```
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 3073659
Purge done for trx's n:o < 3073652 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 50
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 329336420829928, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 329336420832688, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 329336420829008, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 3073648, ACTIVE 787 sec
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 8
MySQL thread id 214186, OS thread handle 47861983655680, query id 15169572 46.14.97.154 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 3073648, sees < 3073648
```

I also took a look at the timeout variables on the server. All of them are set on the default value, but none of them is set around 900s (15 minutes). Is it possible ot reduce this timeout to execute other transactions?